# How to show ProgressDialog while waiting for HttpRespons?

Tags: android, pdf-generation, httprequest, httpresponse, progressdialog

Hi all and thanks for reading. :)

I have this Java (Android) code which is making a HTTP request and waiting for a respons. The request starts a service that generates a PDF-file and returns it.

The service takes about 20 seconds, and while the user is waiting I want to show a progress dialog (indefinate). I've tried showing the dialog in it's own thread which gives me runtime exceptions. I've tried putting the request and respons in their own thread but then there's no waiting for the respons to complete and i get an empty pdf.

Can anyone suggest anything? here's the code...

```
textContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent getPdfFile = null;
    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + fileId.trim() + ".pdf");

    if(!pdfFile.exists()) {

      try {

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet((
                         "http://myServices.mySite.org/services.ashx/PDFFILE?fileId="
                         + fileId + "&account=" + accountId + "&dataset=" +                                                                                              
                         account.getProperty("DATASET").getValue().toString().trim()).replace(" ", "%20"));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getMethod);

        InputStream inStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + fileId.trim() + ".pdf");

        int dataByte = inStream.read();
        while(dataByte > -1) {
          fileWriter.write(dataByte);
          dataByte = inStream.read();
        }
        fileWriter.close();
      }
      catch(Exception e) {

        // TODO: Handle the exceptions...
      }

      getPdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile), "application/pdf");                                    
      startActivity(getPdfIntent);
  }
});
```

Big thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT:** Here's an example where I've used AsyncTask to try and solve the problem.

```
    textContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(final View view) {

        Intent getPdfFile = null;
        File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + fileId.trim() + ".pdf");

        if(!pdfFile.exists()) {

          new AsyncTask<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>() {

              private ProgressDialog dialog;

              protected void onPreExecute() {

                  dialog = ProgressDialog.show(view.getContext(), "Loading", "Please wait...");
              }

              protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... unused) {

                  try {

                      DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                      HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet((
                                   "http://myServices.mySite.org/services.ashx/PDFFILE?fileId="
                                   + fileId + "&account=" + accountId + "&dataset=" +                                                                                                
                                   account.getProperty("DATASET").getValue().toString().trim()).replace(" ", "%20"));
                      HttpResponse response = client.execute(getMethod);

                      InputStream inStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                      FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + fileId.trim() + ".pdf");

                      int dataByte = inStream.read();
                      while(dataByte > -1) {
                          fileWriter.write(dataByte);
                          dataByte = inStream.read();
                      }
                      fileWriter.close();
                  }
                  catch(Exception e) {

                      // TODO: Handle the exceptions...
                  }
                  return true;
              }

              protected void onPostExecute(Boolean unused) {

                  dialog.dismiss();
              }
          }.execute(0);

          getPdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile), "application/pdf");                                   
          startActivity(getPdfIntent);
      }
   });
```

But what happens is that i doesn't wait for the response from the HttpRequest and continues as if the response was returned immidiately. :-/

Comment: you are making a network call on the ui thread. you are not supposed to do that. use an async task instead.

Comment: njzk2 is correct and I think it is actually not allowed on Android 3.0 SDK and above

Comment: Just edited my post to include the AsyncTask that I have tried, without any luck.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? please... it's one the last things remaining to complete version one. :)

Comment: Have you tried changing the return value? For some reason I remember having to adjust the return value of a method to stop it running anything else..

Comment: I'm so sorry guys.... this ones working just fine! I don't know what whent wrong in my head... I need to make my main thread (UI-thread) wait for the AsyncTask thread. Anyone know how to do that? :)

Comment: I've made this ugly code to make it wat... boolean downloaded = false; while(!downloaded) { /*waiting...*/ }. But then the ProgressDialog is omitted. It doesn't show up. If i remove my "ugly-wait" code and try again, it tries starting the pdf intent give me error and when I press back the ProgressDialog is running fine and stop when file is downloaded... :-|

Comment: @RichB is correct on this one.  You need to move your `getPdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fakturaFil), "application/pdf");                                   
          startActivity(getPdfIntent);` lines of code into your `onPostExecute()`.  Right now, you're creating the task, starting it, and then IMMEDIATELY going to the next activity.  You need to wait until the task is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to put your last two lines inside of an `else {}` block and also in the `onPostExecute`so that it only executes if the file exists or after the AsyncTask has completed.

Comment: I love you guys, thanks a lot! This fixed everything. I don't know why i didn't think of it myself, but big thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an AsyncTask ... this tutorial should give you the basics.

http://droidapp.co.uk/?p=177

Comment: Here's what i've done... show dialog in the onPreExecute method, make request in the doInBackground method and dismiss dialog in the onPostExecute method. What happens is that it continues to try and show the pdf file before the response is done. In other words it doesn't wait for the response to end. And when I get the error message that the file can't be read and press back it shows the dialog which never gets dismissed?? :-|

Comment: Can you amend your first post and put the new code you're using in?

Comment: link die pls fix

Answer (score 0):

u should use AsyncTask to do this.  on the override method "doInBackground" u can post your httppost and showdialog on override method "onPreExecute" ,then cancel it on "onPostExecute"

Comment: This is exactly what I've tried but it wont wait for the response, it just continues.

Comment: I dont understand that u mean u only do a http request,then u wont be care of response. But your question is how to [show] progressdialog when waiting response... what ever..I think maybe u can use a hanlder to do this.